# azure pipelines - creating subfolder under wwwroot

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm setting a CI/CD using Azure Pipelines. As the output of the build, I'm generating a zip file. If I manually upload the produced zip artifact to wwwroot using Kudu, it works fine. However, using the Release of Azure Pipelines, it's creating a new folder and dropping the content into it.

[image]

Kudu:
[image]

I've tried several different approaches:

```
-without zipping the output of the build
-using msbuild rather than dotnet build
-deploying using msdeploy
-cloning from existing builds / releases
```

For all the previous approaches I'm getting the same result: the output inside Backoffice folder. I've found a similar problem on [VSTS release pipeline to Azure web app deploys to wwwroot subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451742/vsts-release-pipeline-to-azure-web-app-deploys-to-wwwroot-subdirectory) but I did the steps described in the answer and I'm still with the problem. Any clues?

Comment: And what is your config in Azure (Virtual applications and directories)? what is the physical path for the default virtual path "/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using the Zip Deployment from preview version.